# create Realm DB for each user in Chat App

Tags: swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

this one for sending message and save it to realm db

```
 var messageIndex = try! Realm().objects(MessageRealm.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "timeStamp")

 func didPressSend(text: String) {
    if self.inputContinerView.inputTextField.text! != "" {
        let messageDB = MessageRealm()
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let userRealm = UsersRealm()

        messageDB.textDownloadded = text
        messageDB.fromId = user!.fromId
        messageDB.timeStamp = Date()
        print(messageDB)

        try! realm.write ({
            print(realm.configuration.fileURL)
            userRealm.msgs.append(messageDB)
            //realm.create(MessageRealm.self, value: ["textDownloadded": text, "fromId": user!.fromId, "timeStamp": Date()])
        })
        if let userTitleName = user?.toId {
            print(userTitleName)
            OneMessage.sendMessage(text, thread: "AAAWatree", to: userTitleName, isPhoto: false, isVideo: false, isVoice: false, isLocation: false, timeStamp: date, completionHandler: { (stream, message) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    OneMessage.sharedInstance.deleteCoreDataMessage()
                }
                self.inputContinerView.inputTextField.text! = ""
            })
        }
    }
}
```

This for when recieving message im trying to save user (send id )

```
  let realm = try! Realm()
                    userData.sender = sender
                    userData.toId = toUser
                    print(userData.sender)
                    print(userData.toId)
                        try! realm.write ({
                            realm.add(userData, update: true)

                        })
```

this my Realm Object Class

```
class MessageRealm: Object {

dynamic var textDownloadded = String()
dynamic var imageDownloadded = NSData()
dynamic var videoDownloadded = String()
dynamic var voiceDownloadded = String()
dynamic var fromId = String()
dynamic var timeStamp = Date()
dynamic var messageId = NSUUID().uuidString
let userSelect = List<UsersRealm>()
override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "messageId"
}

}
```

class UsersRealm: Object {

```
dynamic var sender = String()
dynamic var fromId = String()
dynamic var toId = String()
dynamic var lastMessage = String()
dynamic var timeStamp = Date()
dynamic var profileImage = NSData()
let msgs = List<MessageRealm>()
override class func primaryKey() -> String {
    return "sender"
}    
}
```

sending and reciving is ok and its save to realm db but all any user send message i recived in one user i want to seprate for every user have his sending and recive database i miss something here but i dont know i try to search nothing its long question but i cant figure out the soluation

and sorry for my week english
Thank you

Comment: did you found solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your case correctly you're using a single realm url for all users that's why all your clients have the same data. You should probably create a separate realm for the conversation and share it between the users who participate in that chat. Please learn more about sharing realms in our docs at https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#access-control.